# при создание галереи большая картинка не маштабируется по высоте

Tags: javascript, jquery, css3

```
       <div class="gallery">
    <ul class="img-list">
        <li><a href="street/img1.jpg"><img class="pok" src="http://luxfon.com/large/201505/35100.jpg"></a></li>
        <li><a href="street/img2.jpg"><img class="pok" src="http://luxfon.com/large/201203/4217.jpg"></a></li>
        <li><a href="street/img3.jpg"><img class="pok" src="https://www.1zoom.ru/big2/260/289492-alexfas01.jpg"></a></li>
        <li><a href="street/img4.jpg"><img class="pok" src="https://f.usemind.org/img/6/NeedFull.NET_foto-kartinki-plyazh-zontiki-na-plyazhe-more5.jpg"></a></li>
        <li><a href="street/img5.jpg"><img class="pok" src="https://5dwallpaper.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/07/Red-Cherry-Blossom-Flowers-Macro-android-HD-wallpaper-wp1006645.jpg"></a></li>
    </ul>
    <div class="lightbox">
        <div class="overlay"></div>
        <figure>
        <span class="prev">prev</span>
        <span class="next">next</span>
            <img class="big" src="">

        </figure>
        </div>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>>
<script src="functions.js"></script>

 css----------------------------
         .lightbox{

        display: none;
        position: fixed;
        top: 0;
        left: 0;
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        text-align: center;
        padding: 25px 0;
        overflow-y:scroll;
        }
        .overlay{
        position: absolute;
        z-index: -1;
       top: 0;
       left: 0;
       width: 100%;
       height: 100%;
       background-color: rgba(100, 0, 0, .8);
       }
       .big{
       object-fit: cover;
       max-height: 100%;
       min-height: 100%;
       height: 100%;
       width: 100%;
       margin: 0;
       }
       jqwery---------------------------
        var $li = $('.img-list').find('>li'),
        $links = $li.find('>a'),
        $lightbox = $('.lightbox'),
        $overlay = $('.overlay'),
        $prev = $('.prev'),
        $next = $('.next'),
        liIndex,
        targetImg;



        for(var i=0; i < imgSources.length; i++){
        imgs[i] = new Image();
        imgs[i].src = imgSources[i];
        }
        function replaseImg(src){
        $lightbox.find('img').attr('src', src);
        }

        function getHref(index){
        return $li.eq(index + 1).find('>a').attr('href');
        }

        $links.click(function(event){
        event.preventDefault();
        liIndex = $(this).parent().index();
        targetImg = $(this).attr('href');
        replaseImg(targetImg);
        $lightbox.fadeIn();
        });
       $overlay.click(function(){
       $lightbox.fadeOut();
        });
       $prev.click(function(){
       if (liIndex > 0){

       targetImg =getHref(liIndex -1);
       liIndex --;
        } else{

       targetImg = getHref($li.length - 1 );
       liIndex = $li.length - 1;
        }

       replaseImg(targetImg);
       });

      $next.click(function(){
      if((liIndex + 1)<$li.length){
      targetImg = getHref(liIndex + 1);
      liIndex ++;
      } else{
      targetImg = getHref(0);
      liIndex = 0;
      }

       replaseImg(targetImg);
       });
```

---

проблема в том, что когда жмешь на миниатюру и выходит большое изображение то оно не маштабируется по высоте экрана, а именно фотографии вытянутые в длину они не умещаются  в высоту экрана и идет скролинг, как заставить вертикальные фотографии  не превышать высоту экрана. Галерея должна быть адаптивная. За ранее благодарен!

Comment: А "за пOзднее"? Маштабирование!

Comment: о чем это  вы пишете не пойму?

Answer (score 0):

отвечаю сам себе на свой же вопрос, сразу хочу заметить что проблему не мог решить больше недели все облазил и уже отчаявшись начал писать на форумы...
 так вот проблема решается так: надо задать блоку контейнеру img width:100%,
 height: 100vh; vh это еденица измерения области видимости экрана 100 равно высоте экрана ВСЕ!!!